# "Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available.." only in Google Search Results

Tags: seo, google-search, wordpress, meta-description, youtube

Why am I getting this search description in Google search (on any browser):

> "Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats
>   available. Click here to visit our frequently asked questions about
>   HTML5 ..."

It doesn't happen in other search engines like duckduckgo.com and the embed is just a simple iframe code for YouTube in a Wordpress site. Very annoying and is likely turning off users from clicking on links. Thanks for any help.

Comment: When you get that error message, is it possible to play the video's or not?

Comment: The page/post with the video on the site works 100% fine, it's just the search result description in Google. So idk if this is just a google bug or what.

Comment: Are the videos embedded to your page/site using an ‘iframe’?
Can you try using the native WordPress video widget instead?
I just read a post regarding your issue @ https://wordpress.org/support/topic/website-search-description-problem/

Comment: I’ve checked the official ‘WordPress’ support website and there are quite a lot of issues logged with the error you posted. Check: https://wordpress.org/search/your+browser+does+not+intext%3A%22Plugin%3A+All+in+One+SEO+Pack%22/?forums=1

Comment: I'm seeing this issue on all sorts of sites across the web (including one of my own, non-word press site). My youtube video is embedded as an iframe, and rendered with ember fasboot. I started a bounty to hopefully get to the bottom of this.

Comment: I think the real question is: Why is Googlebot seemingly seeing this response when crawling your website? This should be testable/repeatable with the "Fetch as Google / URL Inspection" tool in GSC?

Comment: Are you using any plugins or pasting in the iframe directly to the Wordpress page? Can you share website link?

Comment: @BananaNeil I refunded your bounty so that I could close this question as a duplicate of an older question with more upvotes.    You are welcome to create a bounty on the other question.  Unfortunately it does not have any answers either.